# Determine Width of TLabel

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, tlabel

Hello Stack Overflow Users

I have a `TGroupBox` with a `TLabel` in it. With this `TLabel` I want to display the surname and names of a candidate. Some candidates have more than one name, sometimes three, and when that happens, the `TLabel` doesn't always fit inside my `TGroupBox`. When that happens, I only display the surname, the first name, and the rest I only as initials.

In order to do this, I need to know whether the `TLabel` is going to fit if the values were to be assigned to it. In other words, I need to determine what the width of the `TLabel` is going to be before actually assigning the values to its `Caption` property, for that would be bad programming to display variable data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using VCL or FMX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a very easy and short way to do this. Basically, you just want to know the width of a string in pixels, so the best way to achieve this is to dynamically create an object that has a `Font` and `Canvas` property. I thought `TBitmap` will be the best option. Here’s the code I used:

```
var
  sString: string;
  bmWidth: TBitmap;
  iWidth: Integer;
begin
  sString := edtEdit.Text;
  bmWidth := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    bmWidth.Canvas.Font.Assign(lblLabel.Font);
    iWidth := bmWidth.Canvas.TextWidth(sString);
  finally
    bmWidth.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

In VCL, `TLabel` uses the Win32 API [`DrawText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498.aspx) function to calculate the text width, using [`GetDC()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144871.aspx) to get the `HDC` of the screen and then [`SelectObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162957.aspx)  to select its current `Font` into that `HDC`.  You will have to do the same in your own code, eg:

```
// set Label1.AutoSize to False and Label1.Width to
// the max width your UI will accept the Label1 to be...

function WillFitInLabel(Label: TLabel; const S: String): Boolean;
var
  R: TRect;
  C: TCanvas;
  DC: HDC;
begin
  R := Rect(0, 0, Label.Width, 0);
  C := TCanvas.Create;
  try
    DC := GetDC(0);
    try
      C.Handle := DC;
      try
        C.Font := Label1.Font;
        Windows.DrawText(DC, PChar(S), Length(S), R, DT_SINGLELINE or DT_CALCRECT);
      finally
        C.Handle := 0;
      end;
    finally
      ReleaseDC(0, DC);
    end;
  finally
    C.Free;
  end;
  Result := (R.Width <= Label.Width);
end;

var
  Names: String;
begin
  Names := ...;
  if WillFitInLabel(Label1, Names) then
    Label1.Caption := Names
  else
    ...
end;
```

Comment: See also `TCanvas.TextWidth` ([VCL](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCustomCanvas.TextWidth) and [FMX](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.TextWidth)).

Comment: In VCL, `TCanvas.TextWidth()` uses the Win32 `GetTextExtentPoint32()` function, which does not calculate things the same way that the Win32 `DrawText()` function does. `TLabel` uses `DrawText()` for both calculations and drawing.

Answer (score -1):

If you want wrapping long text in multi lines then you can use label's property `WordWrap := True` and `AutoSize := True`.